# Generating XML Data from Java Code to store in column of XMLTYPE

Tags: java, oracle, dom, sax, xmltype

I have to store XML Data via Java code into Oracle `XMLTYPE` column. I want the data to be generated dynamically rather than providing a hard coded `String` . Performance is also one of the concern,need to generate large XML files. What would be an approriate way to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [xml builder](https://code.google.com/p/java-xmlbuilder/), to generate dynamically.

XML Builder is a utility that creates simple XML documents using relatively sparse Java code

Comment: @Alexandaru Can you provide me with sample code of how to generate a XMl of type    
    `<attribute>
    <id> </id>
    <attributeId> </attributeId>
    <attributeName> </attributeName>
    <previousValue> </previousValue>
    <currentValue> </currentValue>
    </attribute>
`